# Converting a PHP array to a SOAP structure

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I'm picking up an old project that uses SOAP and WSDL, something that I'm not too familiar with. I have the following data structure defined in the WSDL (simplified in this example):

```
<s:complexType name="RequestPayment">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" name="ProviderData" type="s0:ArrayOfFieldPairOfNameString"/>
    </s:sequence>
    <s:attribute name="CancelURL" type="s:string"/>
    <s:attribute name="ReturnURL" type="s:string"/>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfFieldPairOfNameString">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Field" nillable="true" type="s0:PairOfNameString"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="PairOfNameString">
    <s:simpleContent>
        <s:extension base="s:string">
            <s:attribute name="Name" type="s:string" use="required"/>
        </s:extension>
    </s:simpleContent>
</s:complexType>
```

The project is using nusoap, a portion of my PHP looks like:

```
$payment['ProviderData'] = array(
    'Field' => array(
        'Name' => 'Foo',
    ),
);
```

Which is able to produce the following (again, simplified here):

```
<payment>
    <ProviderData>
        <Field Name="Foo" />
    </ProviderData>
</payment>
```

I'm not sure what format my PHP array should be in, in order to produce XML that looks like the following:

```
<payment>
    <ProviderData>
        <Field Name="name 1">value 1</Field>
        <Field Name="name 10">value 10</Field>
        <Field Name="name 2">value 2</Field>
    </ProviderData>
</payment>
```

I've tried setting a key called `Value`, `!Value`, and other variations, without success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not using `XMLWriter` ? http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

Comment: Because its a legacy project, in production and I don't want to have to change more than necessary.

Comment: So you are using a nusoap function to generate the xml from  array? Or some selfmade function?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6743230/4916265

Comment: Yes, I call the WSDL method, using nusoap, and it generates the XML, e.g. `$this->client->call('Payment', $params)`

Comment: Then look how the array is converted and how attributes and values are handled, what kind of name needed and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working backwards (converting the XML example into PHP), the format you want is:

```
$payment['ProviderData'] = array(
   'Field' => array (
     0 =>
     array (
       '!Name' => 'Foo',
       '!' => 'Bar',
     ),
     1 =>
     array (
       '!Name' => 'Amount',
       '!' => '98',
     ),
   )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to use a WSDL to php generator susch as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project as you won't wonder how to construct the request